# Find $n$ in $8n^2 \le 64n\lg n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, logarithms, linear-programming

Given the solution.
Can someone help me why $n \le 43$. What is the step by step of the solution for this?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what isn't clear here...first step: divide both sides by $\,8n\,$ , second step: divide both sides by $\,8n\,$ again (so we could have saved one step and divide from the begining by $\,64n^2\,$)....so?

Comment: I see OP has come back to edit, but has not had anything to say about the two answers that have been posted. Would OP care to interact a bit with those who are trying to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, show by calculus that $\lg n/n$ is decreasing in $n$, so the inequaltiy is satisfied for $n\le n_0$, where we have to work out $n_0$.

Then you can find $n_0=43$, either by educated trial-and-error (just try a lot of values of $n$ until you deduce $43$ is right), or by finding an approximate solution to $1/8=\lg n/n$ by, say, Newton's Method.

Comment: Hello @Gerry. sorry for no response. i been so busy studying logarithms and searching for some resources. I found a link http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8n%5E2%3D64n+log_2+n.. Is the solution correct? What kind of mathematical techniques is used?

Comment: That link gives you a solution in terms of something Wolfram calls "the product log function," which is, I think, what other people call the Lambert W-function. If you follow the links on that page to learn about the product log function, you will probably find that no mathematical techniques are used, but that the W-function is defined in such a way as to make it the answer to the question. Anyway, there are many resources on the web for learning about this function, and it has come up in many questions on this website --- just do a search for the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$ 8n^2 \leq 64n\log n \Rightarrow n^2 \leq 8n\log n$$

This is by simply dividing by 8 on both sides of the inequality. Dividing by $n$ on both sides gives

$$ n \leq 8\log n$$
$$ \Rightarrow \frac{1}{8} \leq \frac{\log n}{n}$$

by dividing by 8 and $n$ on both sides. Then here you can see that if we are picking some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, a common method is trial and error, though there are more precise methods. However, I expect this is the one you should use in this case.

Comment: OP uses the notation $\lg$. I think that's the base $2$ logarithm.

Comment: Alright, I'll adjust my post accordingly. Wasn't aware of that. Thanks @GerryMyerson

Comment: assuming base 2 logarithm, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/58wrhjypdg